# Using a specific Node.js version in Gandi Simple Hosting

Tags: node.js, nvm

basically, I am Using Gandi Simple Hosting for a Node.js application. I would like to use a specific Node.js version. I'm ready that all I had to do was making a ".nvmrc" file and putting the required version number in it.

Now my .nvmrc file looks like this.

```
6.11.0
```

And my package.json file is like this.

```
{
  "name": "name-of-my-app",
  "version": "0.3.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.x",
    "socket.io": "1.x",
    "mysql": "2.x",
    "ejs": "2.x",
    "emailjs": "1.x",
    "svg-captcha": "1.x",
    "sitemap": "1.x",
    "discord.js": "11.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  }
}
```

When I restart my server, the console says the following.

> /srv/data/web/vhosts/default /srv/data/web/vhosts/default
>
> N/A: version "N/A" is not yet installed.
>
> You need to run "nvm install N/A" to install it before using it.

Despite looking at the Gandi documentation, I can't find out what is wrong.

Thanks you in advance for your help! :-)

Noël.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from the Gandi Technical Assistance.

I was told to deploy my code using Git. I made it work by following these inscructions: https://wiki.gandi.net/en/simple/git.